# Python: how to retain the file extension when renaming files with os?

Tags: python, csv, file-extension, file-rename

Say I have a folder with n `csv` files which I want to rename. The new filename is going to be something like `ABxxxx`, with `xxxx` being a progressive number from 1 to 1000.

**While doing this, how can I retain the original file extension, which is `csv`?**

What I have done so far has changed the filenames but has pruned away the extension:

```
directory=r'C:\Me\MyDir'
subdir=[x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)]
subdir.pop(0)

for i in subdir:
    temp_dir=r''+i
    os.chdir(temp_dir)
    a='A'
    b='B'
    for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        for i in range(1,1001):
           newname=a+b+i
        os.rename(file,newname)
```

Comment: Add `.csv` to `newname`?

Comment: Like `newname+".csv"`?

Comment: get the last four characters of the filename - ```ext = filename[-4:]```, assign it to a variable, use that variable to construct a new filename.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply append `'.csv'` to your new filename:

```
os.rename(file, newname + '.csv')
```

In general (for any file type), a better way to do this would be to get the existing extension first using [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) and then append that to the new filename.

```
oldext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
os.rename(file, newname + oldext)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.splitext` to build a tuple of `(basepath, extension)` and `enumerate` to generate your "uniquifier". Now you can just use vanilla string formatting to glue it together

```
for i in subdir:
    temp_dir=r''+i
    os.chdir(temp_dir)
    a='A'
    b='B'
    for idx, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
        os.rename(file,'{0}{2}{1}'.format(*(os.path.splitext(file) + (idx,))))
```